# how to add column base on one row in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this table

```
Row Title   Code    RegDate     Amount
----------------------------------------------------------
1   typea   203170  1396/12/29  150760000000    --Eur
1   typea   203251  1396/12/29  169928736       --Usd
2   typeb   201310  1396/12/29  32794373868351
3   typec   201441  1396/12/29  899750000
6   typed   201216  1396/12/29  23411268063599
8   typee   201181  1396/12/29  86687000        --Eur
8   typee   201211  1396/12/29  81483719480611  --Usd
9   typef   201212  1396/12/29  52595043810
10  typeh   201213  1396/12/29  3630924097
```

how i can combine Row 1 and 8 to one row like this result

```
Row Title   Code    RegDate     Amount          Amount_Usd
----------------------------------------------------------
1   typea   203170  1396/12/29  150760000000    169928736
2   typeb   201310  1396/12/29  32794373868351  0
3   typec   201441  1396/12/29  899750000       0
6   typed   201216  1396/12/29  23411268063599  0
8   typee   201181  1396/12/29  86687000        81483719480611
9   typef   201212  1396/12/29  52595043810     0
10  typeh   201213  1396/12/29  3630924097      0
```

default amount is eur
thanks

Comment: How do you know which amount is in Euros and which is in US Dollars?

Comment: with code , just 203251  ,201211   is usd,all codes is eur

Comment: USD 81483719480611  is huge amount. And your company let beginners do the programming?

Comment: this amounts is sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need some conditional aggregation here:

```
--Sample Data
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1   ,'typea',203170,'1396/12/29',150760000000),
                (1   ,'typea',203251,'1396/12/29',169928736),   
                (2   ,'typeb',201310,'1396/12/29',32794373868351),
                (3   ,'typec',201441,'1396/12/29',899750000),
                (6   ,'typed',201216,'1396/12/29',23411268063599),
                (8   ,'typee',201181,'1396/12/29',86687000),
                (8   ,'typee',201211,'1396/12/29',81483719480611),
                (9   ,'typef',201212,'1396/12/29',52595043810),
                (10  ,'typeh',201213,'1396/12/29',3630924097)) V([Row],Title,Code, RegDate, Amount))
--Solution
SELECT Row,
       Title,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Code NOT IN (203251,201211) THEN Code END) AS Code,
       RegDate,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Code NOT IN (203251,201211) THEN Amount END),0) AS Amount,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Code IN (203251,201211) THEN Amount END),0) AS Amount_Usd
FROM VTE
GROUP BY [Row],[Title],RegDate;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=45ca411abbf5c13c2631150528a29d13)

*No need for a CTE, my coffee hadn't kicked in.*

Comment: . . You should fix the explanation.  It doesn't match the query.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. I'd amended the SQL, but not the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try This-

```
SELECT A.Row,A.Title,B.Code,A.RegDate,A.Amount,A.Amount_Usd FROM
(
    SELECT Row,Title,RegDate,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Code NOT IN (203251 ,201211) THEN Amount ELSE NULL END),0) Amount,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Code IN (203251 ,201211) THEN Amount ELSE NULL END),0)Amount_Usd
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY Row,Title,RegDate
)A
INNER JOIN your_table B
ON A.Row = B.Row  and B.Code NOT IN (203251 ,201211)
```

Comment: Have you tried that? It doesn't do what the OP wants. [db<.fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c98de974a7a4ca1ca81696535efcdeae)

Comment: Updated. There were some issue regarding adding code in the GROUP BY.